# How to Access "My Computer" files from Command Prompt

Tags: android, batch-file, command-line, shared-folders

I'm trying to figure out how to access files on "My Computer" from the command prompt. In particular, I want to access files on my phone's share, e.g.,

**My Computer\SAMSUNG\Phone\somefile.txt**.
That file *does* show up in Explorer.

I've searched unsuccessfully for a solution on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but no joy. I found countless solutions for starting Windows Explorer on that folder, but that is **NOT** what I need to do.

In particular, I'd like to do something like

**NOTEPAD "\\My Computer\SAMSUNG\Phone\somefile.txt"**

BTW - That *doesn't* work.

I'd like to do this because I have various batch files and setup programs that I want to run against files on my phone. I could setup the files on C: and then copy to the desired folder from Explorer, but that's a pain and unable to be automated.

I'm beginning to think that this is impossible, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How impossible it is depends on your phone. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57429/open-command-prompt-to-access-folders-of-a-usb-connected-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

> I could setup the files on C: and then copy to the desired folder from Explorer, but that's a pain and unable to be automated

That's not true. Explorer is an object browser so there is no concept of files. Just objects.

This is code running a right click - Verb against a shell object.

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo(Cmd.doit)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

This is code using Shell Objects to make a zip file.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```